# tqdm — display current step and total progress. How?

Tags: python, tqdm

For example, when processing N files of different lengths, you want to see both the file-by-file progress (M out of N) and the total time progress, taking into account their size.
Simple emulation:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

fmt = '{n_fmt} of {total_fmt} {percentage:3.0f}%'
iteration = (3, 2, 1, 4)  # filesize
bar = tqdm(total=sum(iteration), miniters=1, bar_format=fmt)
for i in iteration:  # by file process
    sleep(i)
    bar.update(i)
```

the bar will display progress by size:

```
3 of 10  30%
5 of 10  50% 
6 of 10  60%
10 of 10 100%
```

need:

```
1 of 4  30%
2 of 4  50% 
3 of 4  60%
4 of 4 100%
```

How?

Answer (score 0):

Based on a snippet from the help, on introducing a custom parameter to the progressbar.

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep

class TqdmTick(tqdm):
    def __init__(self, ticks, *args, **kwargs):
        self._ticks = ticks
        self._tick = 0
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def tick(self, value):
        self._tick += 1
        self.update(value)

    @property
    def format_dict(self):
        d = super().format_dict
        d.update(tick=str(self._tick), ticks=str(self._ticks))
        return d

fmt = '{tick} of {ticks} {percentage:3.0f}%'

iteration = (3, 2, 1, 4)
bar = TqdmTick(ticks=len(iteration), total=sum(iteration), bar_format=fmt)

for i in iteration:
    sleep(i)
    bar.tick(i)
```